# PHP SoapFault detail namespace

Tags: php, soap, namespaces, soapserver, soapfault

I'm trying to return a SoapFault from PHP SoapServer, but am stuck with creating the right format of response.

When handling exceptions, I am returning:

```
$detail = "message";
return new SoapFault("Client", "ValidationException", null, $detail, "ValidationException");
```

and the response looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
      <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>ValidationException</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <ValidationException>
          <message>message</message>
        </ValidationException>
      </detail>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

However, I'd like the response to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
      <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>ValidationException</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <ns2:ValidationException xmlns:ns2="http://service.applicationsnet.com/soap/">
          <message>message</message>
        </ns2:ValidationException>
      </detail>
    </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I tried several things, but unsuccessfully. Can you please help me?

Another thing with namespaces, is it possible to change the "SOAP-ENV" envelope namespace? Thanks.

Comment: You mean the prefix "SOAP-ENV"? Like name it "ENV-SOAP" or "ENVELOPE" or whatever?

Comment: No idea if it is possible (neither by PHP *nor* by SOAP), see http://php.net/soapfault.soapfault for a PHP manual page about this.

Comment: Yeah I know about the page.. I can change the prefix "SOAP-ENV" by extending SoapServer class and changing the substring before sending each response.. However, the main question I asked was about the "ns2"  namespace in SoapFault detail. Thanks for the thought though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's still relevant but to define a soapfault like the one you want the right soapfault type has to be defined in the wsdl.

Take your wsdl and inside it write an operation with soapFault like this

```
<wsdl:operation name="TransferFundsRequest">
    <wsdl:input name="request" message="tns:TransferFundsRequest" />
    <wsdl:output name="response" message="tns:TransferFundsResponse" />
    <wsdl:fault name="fault" message="tns:ExceptionType" />
</wsdl:operation>`
```

where the fault type is

```
<xsd:complexType name="ExceptionType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Code" type="xsd:integer" />
        <xsd:element name="Message" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Could you make your answer a bit more clear, such as splitting it into several sentences, or showing some code?